# How to create and manage menus in sprite kit scene

Tags: sprite-kit

What's the best methode for creating menu's in sprite kit?
With UIButton's of with SKSpriteNodes?

I would like to create a menu like the menu on the picture in the link
[image menu](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/artwork/na-ryi/easter_ipad_1.JPG)

How know it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this menu can created by using a SKScene.
You can use a SKSpriteNode for each of mission and manage by a database.

It is only a board with 15 SKSpriteNode (5 in col and 3 on rows).
Each of this have a name (name of SKSpriteNode).
You can know what node is touched and easy to go other scene (playing scene).

If you cannot do, I will go deeper on this questions.